# Generating from recursive definitions with Clojure Spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Let's consider a Clojure Spec regexp for hiccup syntax

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as spec])

(spec/def ::hiccup
  (spec/cat :tag        keyword?
            :attributes (spec/? map?)
            :content    (spec/* (spec/or :terminal string?
                                         :element  ::hiccup))))
```

which works splendidly

```
(spec/conform ::hiccup [:div#app [:h5 {:id "loading-message"} "Connecting..."]])
; => {:tag :div#app, :content [[:element {:tag :h5, :attributes {:id "loading-message"}, :content [[:terminal "Connecting..."]]}]]}
```

until you try to generate some example data for your functions from the spec

```
(require '[clojure.spec.gen :as gen])
(gen/generate (spec/gen ::hiccup))
; No return value but:
; 1. Unhandled java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
;    GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Is there a way to rewrite the spec so that it produces a working generator? Or do we have to attach some simplified generator to the spec?

Answer (score 3):

The intent of `spec/*recursion-limit*` (default 4) is to limit recursive generation such that this should work. So either that's not working properly in one of the spec impls (`*` or `or`), or you are seeing rapid growth in something else (like `map?` or the strings). Without doing some tinkering, it's hard to know which is the problem.

This does generate (a very large example) for me:

```
(binding [spec/*recursion-limit* 1] (gen/generate (spec/gen ::hiccup)))
```

I do see several areas where the cardinalities are large even in that one example - the `*` and the size of the generated attributes `map?`. Both of those could be further constrained. It would be easiest to break these parts up further into more fine-grained specs and supply override generators where necessary (the attribute map could just be handled with `map-of` and `:gen-max`).

Comment: So I limited :attributes to be a `(spec/? (spec/map-of keyword? string? :gen-max 1))`. With that, setting `spec/*recursion-limit*` to 3 brings generation time to 1-5s. But if we increase the limit to 4 we're back to endless evaluation until the GC overhead limit is exceeded. How would you recommend limiting how large the generated data of `*`grows? Assuming I'm correct in believing that's the issue.

Comment: Worth noting [CLJ-1978: recursion-limit not respected](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1978).