# How do I limit size of generated sample with `clojure.spec/+`?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec, test.check

`clojure.spec/coll-of` takes `:gen-max` option to limit the generated sample size.
Is there an analog for `clojure.spec/+`?

Comment: Related subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538198/generating-from-recursive-definitions-with-clojure-spec

Answer (score 1):

`s/*` and `s/+` don't take an option like `:gen-max` but those repetitive regex specs do [take `clojure.spec.alpha/*recursion-limit*` into account](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha/blob/11d21c5f055f49b6a84554837b80c91be831c058/src/main/clojure/clojure/spec/alpha.clj#L1647). I think that's fairly coarse-grained control and has no practical effect on simple specs like this, which seemingly always generate a longest sequence of ~200 elements for any positive `*recursion-limit*`:

```
(binding [clojure.spec.alpha/*recursion-limit* 1]
  (->> (gen/sample (s/gen (s/* int?)) 200)
       (map count)
       (apply max)))
```

One way to limit the length of the generated sequences is to provide a custom generator:

```
(s/def ::ints
  (s/with-gen
    (s/+ int?)
    #(gen/vector gen/int 1 10)))
(gen/sample (s/gen ::ints) 200)
```

This should always generate a vector of 1-10 integers.